# Build string from a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server Group Concat with Different characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523272/sql-server-group-concat-with-different-characters)

I need an example on SELECT where the output is a ',' separated string

e.g. `SELECT (... something ...) name AS output FROM name_table`

gives me

```
output
-----------------------------
'Ann', 'Tom', 'Wilson', .....
```

How would you do that in SQL server 2008 R2?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to post some idea of the data you're trying to query, and some sort of real attempt to solve the problem. `SELECT (... something ...)` is not a *real attempt*, and you've given no idea of what columns you have in `name_table`. Unless, of course, you're willing to accept `SELECT (... some_columns ...)` as an answer, in which case I'll post it now. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuiming you have a schema like this,

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([GROUP_ID] int, [PERSON_NAME] varchar(6));

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([GROUP_ID], [PERSON_NAME])
VALUES
    (1001, 'ALEX'),
    (1002, 'MATHEW'),
    (1001, 'GEORGE'),
    (1002, 'THOMAS'),
    (1001, 'JAMES');
```

create a query something like this to produce a comma separated value,

```
SELECT
     GROUP_ID,
     STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + PERSON_NAME
          FROM Table1
          WHERE [GROUP_ID] = a.GROUP_ID
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS NamesList
FROM Table1 AS a
GROUP BY GROUP_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3e7a/7)

Comment: Nice and easy! Answer picked! Thanks!